# iOS abnormal behavior of Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, fullscreen, navigationbar

I have a table view A which is segued to a view B.
In A, there is a nav bar on the top, and below is the table.
When I press a row in A's table, B is pushed.
In B's viewWillAppear, I have the following code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
}
```

This makes extends the view so that below the status bar, I have Nav bar and the UIView overlapped. 
I also have viewWillDisappear

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer in the navigation stack.

        self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    }
}
```

So when the user press back button, it will undo the fullscreen mode so that the view and nav bar won't overlap. THE ISSUE IS, when I press back button and the previous screen A is shown, strangely the table view still appears overlapped with the nav bar.
I even tried to put self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO in A's willViewAppear but to no avail.
Shouldn't A shrink the tableview and be located under Nav bar? Can anyone let me know what is worng and how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if it's what's causing your issue, but make sure you are calling [super viewWillAppear:animated]; and [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; if those are your complete method implementations

Comment: okay I think missed them.. But adding them doesn't fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the code in `viewWillDisappear` method, try to put the same code in the `viewWillAppear` method of the previous view controller.

Comment: add this code too
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO

Comment: Still... When I go back, the previous screen appears with Nav bar. The  thing is that the nav bar covers the actual content view..